# How do I run pdflatex without having to stop for errors?

Tags: pdftex

I would like to run pdflatex on a file so that I get all errors and problems at once without ever waiting for my input.

I looked at this:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1037927/run-pdflatex-quietly

but unfortunately the noninteractive and batchmode are not a good fit for me. The noninteractive one, for example, breaks after the first error, while I want it to be as if I pressed enter and moved to the next error.

(I want to send someone all errors for a set of .tex files they sent me.)

Comment: The second answer in  your link has the option `-interaction=nonstopmode`. This is the suggested way but of course it will stop to the first error. I don't think that any latex compiler could (or should) continue and find more errors after first one (that can't get over). Something like this is impossible in every programming language even by using all the current known (to simple people) AI. [didn't noticed the part about the "as if I pressed enter"... In this case my (and @samcarter approach works) ]

Comment: After 1st error, press `r` and `return`?

Comment: `--interaction=nonstopmode` does what you ask, it does not stop at the first error (@koleygr either I don't understand your comment, or it is wrong, nonstopmode is designed so tex will try to report all the errors in the document)

Comment: "all the errors in the document" is not precise.  when an error is such that the input code gets out of synch, succeeding errors may be bogus and never end.  in such a case, tex will (ordinarily?) stop after 100 errors.  (at least, that's what the original tex did; i don't know whether enhanced versions allow a greater number of errors.)  don't be fooled into thinking that all *real* errors will be reported when using nonstop mode.